# Should I use react-native for the web to only build a web app

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

My employer would like me to build an application using React-Native for the web. He only wants a web app. The project is for a client who may want a mobile app down the road. It seems like the best use case is to build both at the same time. Since we are not doing that I suggested we just use React but he is pretty committed to RN for the web, which I am totally willing to do. Are there any reasons not to build just for the web, complications? If we are not going to use it, the client would need a sound list of reasons why, so, if anyone has suggestions, reasons I could list would be helpful. Or, if it is a fine idea, helpful suggestions to keep in mind moving forward. Pretty general I know but I appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One factor to consider would be how far in future would the client want a mobile app. If it is more than a couple of years away then you might have to spend considerable time upgrading libraries (including react-native) and addressing the deprecated APIs when you start building the app in future. In this case it might be easier to simply start with a fresh react-native project with latest library versions instead of spending time upgrading and fixing an older code.
The tradeoff of spending time upgrading libraries vs porting UI components to mobile environment will also depend on your app design and complexity and how well your code is structured.

Another factor to consider would be community and open source libraries available for react native web. According to my understanding, react native for web is relatively new platform and there might not be as many libraries to support your design needs as of today. Maybe your team can do a little research and figure out if there are well maintained libraries available for your design needs and how much time would you have to spend designing components from scratch.

Lastly, regardless of whether or not you design your web app now using react-native web, you will still have to spend significant time testing the mobile app later when the client needs one. Building a web app using react-native does not eliminate the need to thoroughly test a mobile app the app on a mobile platform.

Comment: Thanks, from what I have read it seems like building the mobile and web app in tandem is the base use case. I would think styling for mobile would translate to the web better than styling for the web and trying to get that to translate to mobile. I think you are right about updating all the libraries, I had not thought of that but a fellow employee recently went through that with older RN apps we had built. Thanks for your time, I appreciate your thoughts